# Inject Dispatcher into ViewModel - Recompose Unity - property injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, win-universal-app, prism

I'm trying to inject the Dispatcher of my ShellPage into my ViewModel with Unity and Prism. Because the dispatcher is available after the shell is being created, I can't register the Dispatcher in time.
First step:

```
 protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            [...]
            Container.RegisterInstance<IResourceLoader>(resourceLoader);
```

Secondly the CreateShell method will be executed.

```
protected override UIElement CreateShell(Frame rootFrame)
        {
            var shell = Container.Resolve<ShellPage>();
            Container.RegisterType<MyViewModel>(new InjectionProperty(nameof(MyViewModel.Dispatcher), shell.Dispatcher));
```

Although I inject the Dispatcher into MyViewModel into the propertie Dispatcher is null. Maybe I need something like recomposing in MEF? How can I achieve the propertie injection into MyViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is not possible.
Recomposing like MEF is not supported.

The easy way is creating a helper to get the Dispatcher of the current view and use it in your ViewModels

Please see this example:
http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/fixing-coredispatcher-invoke-how-to-invoke-method-in-ui-thread-in-windows-8-release-preview

This example is for Windows 8 but you can use it for UWP apps

just when I use this approach I do small changes for UWP apps:

In Onlaunched event in app.xaml.cs

I add UIDispatcher in a different place.

```
 if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter

            UIDispatcher.Initialize();
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
```